# How do I make it so that these boxes are in multiple columns as opposed to just 1 column?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to make it so that these columns of days split up into 2 rows with 4 'days' on top and 3 'days' on the bottom as well as being centered on each row. I also wanted to make it so that the corresponding day of the week is a label that sits outside the box while the type of routine (ex: push day, pull day) is a header inside the box while the image sits below the routine header. Any input or help would be appreciated.

React code:

```
import React from "react"
import "./App.css" // Import your CSS file
import NavBar from "./NavBar"

const daysOfWeek = [
    ["Monday", "Push Day"],
    ["Tuesday", "Rest Day"],
    ["Wednesday", "Pull Day"],
    ["Thursday", "Rest Day"],
    ["Friday", "Arms and Shoulders"],
    ["Saturday", "Rest Day"],
    ["Sunday", "Leg Day"],
]

const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <NavBar />
            <div className='home-page'>
                <div className='day-boxes'>
                    {daysOfWeek.map(([day, routine]) => (
                        <div
                            className='day-box'
                            key={day}
                        >
                            <div className='day-label'>{day}</div>
                            <h2>{routine}</h2>
                            <img src='src\assets\Incline-Barbell-Bench-Press.png' />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

CSS code:

```
/* NavBar.css */
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: red; /* Set your desired color */
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.app-name {
    font-size: 24px;
}

/* HomePage.css */
.home-page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.day-boxes {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    gap: 0.25rem;
    margin: 0.5in;
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .day-boxes {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }
}

.day-box {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; /* Set your desired height */
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.day-box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.day-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}

.day-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 80%; /* Adjust this value as needed */
    object-fit: cover;
}
```